# Is possible to use lightning:combobox with grouped options?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-combobox

In the [SLDS documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/#Grouped-options), it is stated the possibility to have a combobox with grouped options.

[image: example]

It is possible to achieve a similar result with the lightning aura component `lightning:combobox`?

In the [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/specification) of `lightning:combobox` is clearly stated that the `options` attribute is a list of objects that have the properties `label` and `value` only and there are no other attributes that suggest the use of something like groups. I'm hoping that I missed something or that there is a workaround to achieve what I want without having to write a custom combobox component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'd have to write your own component. There's no "grouping" feature available in the library `lightning:combobox`.

Comment: Sadly you confirmed my belief.

Comment: It borders on irresponsibility for Salesforce to ship such disastrously under-featured components such as `lightning-combobox` or `lightning:combobox`, without any apparent  thought towards supporting other aspects of the SLDS combobox blueprint. Actually, it appears there *is* a `lightning-grouped-combobox` component, but it's undocumented AFAICS.

Comment: @kamezaburo I agree it's frustrating that the full range of options in the SLDS docs are not available, but it does take time for them to get to everything.

Answer (score 0):

[**I've implemented a custom LWC Grouped Combobox using the SLDS Combobox blueprints.**](https://github.com/LianBond/LWC-Grouped-Combobox)

[image: Example of what the Custom Salesforce LWC Grouped Combobox looks like (built using the SLDS Combobox blueprint)]

lightning:combobox/lightning-combobox does not support grouping and lightning-grouped-combobox is not officially supported yet. If you're willing to go custom, please feel free to use my LWC Grouped Combobox above.